# VB.Net ChildWindow of embedded IE page in Panel Control

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

Using VB.net I am embedding IE Process in Panel Control (Panel1) using "SetParent" , now I am trying to detect the SaveAs Prompt that shows up in the IE page as shown in the image, by using the below code

```
SetParent(IEProcess.Mainwindowhandle, Panel1.Handle)
Do
        h = objIE.HWND
        h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop While h = 0
```

The problem is h is always zero and the save as prompt can't be detected as a child window of IE page.
[image]